# Is it possible to get the address of the first string in memory of a process in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, loops, memory, system

Is it possible to get the address of the first string in memory of a process in c++?
Like i dont have to iterate through the whole memory of the process to find strings but i can start iterating from the address of the first string? I'm talking about finding the first of any type of variable not just string, though i used it as an example.
Let me give an example in code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    std::string buf;
    ReadProcessMemory(hproc, (LPCVOID)i, &buf, sizeof(std::string), NULL);
    std::cout << buf << std::endl;
}
```

Should this be necessary? can't i just start i with the address of the first string, or do this faster any other way?

Comment: Even if you get the address, copying an `std::string` that way is Undefined Behavior. In this case specifically `std::string`'s destructor may `delete` memory, and since this loop destroys the string each iteration it is likely to `delete` random addresses until it crashes.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you clarify please?

Comment: I am trying to print all the strings in a process's memory.

Comment: Are you talking the process' data memory or the process' executable area?

Comment: What happens if the process is swapped out to the hard drive when your process is running?

Comment: Well, also it didn't crash.

Comment: I don't know. But i guess it won't, why would it?

Comment: If this doesn't crash then it is likely that `ReadProcessMemory` failed.

Comment: @MicrosoftSkype BTW, you are aware that `sizeof(std::string)` will leave you with the size of the `std::string` class, and not the underlying data which is probably what you're after? The only thing you could try to check for printable character sequences, which are NUL terminated. The latter could give you an approach for whatever you want to do with this information.

Comment: I have fixed my program.

Comment: *"Is it possible to get the address of the first string in memory"* - Sure, that's possible. Is it useful? Off the top of my head I cannot think of a single problem where this would be a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Std strings allocate their internal storage using the same heap as all other objects allocated using operator new. There is no way to distinguish the various pieces of content.

That said, from a purely intellectual excercise, it is possible to declare your own implementation of basic_string with a custom allocator, where you can watch the memory allocation and deallocation.

The full template definition of std::basic string is:

```
template<
    class CharT,
    class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>
> class basic_string;
```

And std::string is actually `std::basic_string<char>`, relying on the defaults for Traits and Allocator.

Where you could supply your own Allocator implementation, which might, for example, log the allocations and deallocations that your program performs, or store the allocations sequentially in some contiguous storage. You would only be tracking the strings you explicitly declared your way.

Note that move semantics are disabled between standard containers that use different allocators, and in many cases calling std library methods that take or return strings as parameters will invoke a copy between your customised string and a standard allocated version, so the view might still not be a true one.

As I understand it, the current implementations of std::string simply store the character content in the allocated storage, but it is possible to store other information in the allocated space to help manage the string growth.

Note that the capacity and current length of the string is stored in the std::string object that also points to this buffer, so it is difficult to infer much useful about the content of the allocated buffer. If it is being used as a legal string then the c++ standards say that it is zero terminated; so that suggests it could be treated as a C char* string.

Many implementations optimise for very small strings by storing them inline in the std::string object with no dynamic allocation. They rely on some arbitrary rule to understand which layout is current (nullptr or dynamic or inline), such as "knowing" that the capacity, a 64bit integer, can never be bigger than 56 bits value, so the "top byte" is always zero for a dynamic string; but is actually the 1byte size() for an inline string, with a constant max size: The remaining bytes can then be used for the inline content, perhaps up to 23 characters!

But other schemes are possible. For example the old microsoft string (not std::string) used to store all the length and capacity info in the pointed to object at the start, and the string object was a simple pointer to the next text part of the buffer.  This was very convenient for use in printf()! Other pre-c++11 std::string systems tried to share strings and stored reference counts, but the "lifetime" rules for c++11 have made that virtually untenable.